# Approaching Trigonometric Equations graphically.

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm busy working through a section on trigonometric equations in my textbook and not having any problem solving them algebraically, but I'm not entirely sure I have a complete understanding of what is really going on and what the equations are describing. I've made an attempt below at what I think is happening.

For instance, $$\cos(3x) = \sin(2x)$$

Algebraically, simple enough to solve:

$$\sin(2x) = \sin(90^{\circ}-3x)$$
\begin{align}
2x &= 90^{\circ} - 3x + k\cdot360 ^{\circ} \\
5x &= 90^{\circ} + k\cdot360^{\circ} \\
x &= 18^{\circ} + k\cdot72^{\circ}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
2x &= 180^{\circ} - (90^{\circ}-3x) + k\cdot360^{\circ} \\
-x &= 90^{\circ} + k\cdot360^{\circ}\\
x &= -90^{\circ} + k\cdot360^{\circ}
\end{align}

This is how I would graph that equation using a graphing program:

[image: Sin2x = Cos3x]

Would I be correct in saying that graphically $\sin(2x) = \cos(3x)$ describes where the two graphs are intersecting? I'd appreciate any elaboration or correction on this topic.

Thanks in advance! 
- Shaun

Comment: Yes, that is correct. f(x)=g(x) is always the set of all the solutions (x values of points of intersection).

Comment: Yes!, The answer is  where the two graphs are intersecting

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize what was said in the comments, you're exactly right. Whenever you graph two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the $x$-values of the points at which the two functions intersect will be the same values of $x$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)=g(x)$.